# Run npm module like daemon

Tags: npm, daemon

I have downloaded npm teleirc module on my remote computer. I want to run this module like daemon. How I can do it?

```
forever --start
```

This program doesn't work with npm modules.

Comment: I found the solution.
`nohup teleirc &`